# Compiling C code on server with PHP

Tags: php, c

I have this php code

```
<?php
 $Command = "cd /var/www/html/Codiad/workspace/workspace  2>&1; gcc HelloWorld.c; ./a.out"
 $Method1 = exec($Command);
 echo $Method1;
?>
```

The code works fine, it shows the output, but I want only see the output after click on a button. How can I do that remaining on the same page? To be more precise I have two buttons, one for compiling code and one for execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do it with AJAX and make 2 calls. One button clicks makes request that will compile. Other will execute the code.

Comment: This is not worth an answer.

Comment: Though it IS the answer.

Comment: yeah, it is the answer, I'm trying with JQuery and I'm obtaining the first results, thanks!